# NPM Publish does not find package in self hosted gitlab private registry while publishing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, npm-publish, gitlab-omnibus

I already refered different articles and stackoverflow solutions but issue does not get resolved.

We are using self hosted omnibus gitlab (15.11) installed approach in docker container for which our <git.mydomain.com> proxied requests to respective docker container and we have exposed 443, 8081, 80, 22 ports in the docker container.

Following is the content of `.npmrc`:

```
@my-org:registry=https://git.mydomain.com/projects/<project-id>/packages/npm/
//git.mydomain.com/projects/<project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken=$DEPLOY_TOKEN
```

`package.json`

```
"publishConfig": {
    "@my-org:registry": "https://git.mydomain.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/npm/"
}
```

While running `npm publish --verbose`, I am getting following output:

[image]

I have considered following points:

- Trailing space in urls
- Check the authToken url should start with //
- checked the consistency of registry url in `.npmrc` and `package.json`
- checked the consistency of `@scope` in `.npmrc` and `package.json`
- Tried with `CI`*`JOB`*`TOKEN` , DEPLOY TOKEN and ACCESS TOKEN
- Tried replacing registry url to instance level and respective authToken url along with Project level authToke url
- Tried setting with

  - ```
    npm config set @my-org:registry https://git.mydomain.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/npm/
    npm config set //git.mydomain.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/npm/:_authToken <Token>
    ```
- Package Registry is enabled for this project

  [image]
- Explicitly enable Packages Repository  in `gitlab.rb`

  [image]